# How to assign indexes to values in CSV using different lengths. (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, csv, arraylist

I'm trying to align values in two different CSV files to like indexes. One CSV has a unix time stamp every second and the other every minute. Additionally I need to mark the indexes pn various lengths of the data.

So for example I would need to mark minutes 1 - 20 (and seconds 1 - 1200) with the index of 0, then minutes 21 - 25 (1260 - 1500) with index 1, minutes 26 - 42 (1560 - 2520) with index 2, etc. etc.

The length will vary depending on the data (possibly an array that holds the different values for the lengths) that I am using so I would like to do this programatically. I'm not sure how to attack this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit (hopefully this helps clarify some)

I have data in one CSV that has information about audio and another that has information about bio-metric data. They will both have a column that has a unix time stamp. The data in the audio CSV is for every second and the bio-metric data is for every minute.

I want to add an additional row to the CSV's that have the same index(or key) value so that the data has a common link between the two files. If I call index 1 I want to get the data from both files that have an index of 1.

The length of an audio file will determine where the keys start and stop. So if I had an audio file that was 2 minutes long, 2 rows in the bio-metric CSV will have a key of 0 and 120 rows of the audio CSV will have a key of 0.

If that audio file had been 3 minutes long the first 3 rows of the bio-metric CSV would have a key of 0 and the first 180 rows of the audio CSV would have the a key of 0.

Comment: i'm not sure if people can understand your question

Comment: @RafaEl And I thought I just needed more coffee

Comment: @user2310289 no you don't. perhaps OP is the one who need it

Comment: @user2310289 I definitely need more coffee! I edited the post  so I'm sure it's clear as mud now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open both files, read the first line to see what the timestamp is, then read lines from the file that has the earlier timestamp until it no longer has the earlier timestamp, or ends.

If this is `by-minute.csv`:

```
1394589660,minute 1
1394589720,minute 2
```

and this is `by-second.csv`:

```
1394589659,second -1
1394589660,second 0
1394589661,second 1
1394589662,second 2
1394589663,second 3
1394589664,second 4
…
1394589718,second 58
1394589719,second 59
1394589720,second 60
1394589721,second 61
```

then this Java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader byMinute = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream("by-minute.csv")));

        BufferedReader bySecond = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream("by-second.csv")));

        String byMinuteLine = byMinute.readLine();
        String bySecondLine = bySecond.readLine();

        while (byMinuteLine != null || bySecondLine != null) {

            /* If either file is done, print lines from the other file */
            if (byMinuteLine == null) {
                System.out.println(indicize(bySecondLine));
                bySecondLine = bySecond.readLine();
            } else if (bySecondLine == null) {
                System.out.println(indicize(byMinuteLine));
                byMinuteLine = byMinute.readLine();
            } else {
                /* Otherwise print the earlier entry */
                long minuteTime = getTimeStamp(byMinuteLine);
                long secondTime = getTimeStamp(bySecondLine);

                if (secondTime < minuteTime) {
                    System.out.println(indicize(bySecondLine));
                    bySecondLine = bySecond.readLine();
                } else {
                    System.out.println(indicize(byMinuteLine));
                    byMinuteLine = byMinute.readLine();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    static long getTimeStamp(String line) {
        return Long.valueOf(line.split(",")[0]);
    }

    static String indicize(String line) {
        return ((getTimeStamp(line) - 1394589660) / 20)
            + line.substring(line.indexOf(","));
    }

}
```

will print out:

```
0,second -1
0,minute 1
0,second 0
0,second 1
0,second 2
0,second 3
0,second 4
0,second 5
0,second 6
0,second 7
0,second 8
0,second 9
…
2,second 55
2,second 56
2,second 57
2,second 58
2,second 59
3,minute 2
3,second 60
3,second 61
```

Now I know that’s not exactly what you’re looking for—but I hope that’s enough to get you started!